# recovery mode on s4

Tags: recovery-mode

my s4 went into recovery mode and I cant afford to loose all my data by wiping clean to factory mode. which option should I select?
it gives me these12 options~
*reboot sytem now
*apply update from ABD
*apply update from external storage
*wipe data/factory reset
*wipe cachce partition
*reboot to bootloader 
*power down
*view recovery logs
*enable cp logging
*disable cp logging

I have selected and tried the *power down and *wipe cache partition selections and nothing changed.
HELP Please :)

edited:
It powered down on its own and when I went to power back up it goes to this everytime. my phone has been reheating and eating up battery for the past few weeks. somebody told me they guess its board is going bad and about to crash. :( pry what happened. I waited too long to upgrade... I'm guessing rebooting wipes everything to factory setting!!??

Comment: How did it go into recovery mode (guessing accidental key combo)? what does *reboot system* do?

Comment: It just powered down on its own and when I went to power back up it goes to this everytime. my phone has been reheating and eating up battery for the past few weeks. somebody told me they guess its board is going bad and about to crash. :( pry what happened. I waited too long to upgrade... I'm guessing rebooting wipes everything to factory setting!!??

Comment: please add these details to the question by editing (not everyone reads comments) and if possible add a screen shot. Also give out the correct model of your phone and android version

Comment: *rebooting* from recovery mode will not factory reset. Latter happens when you specifically chose that option and devices warn you that choosing that option will result in losing data

Comment: Delaying an upgrade cannot destroy the physical components purposely. Either that, or we could all sue our phone manufacturers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have *that* many options in recovery mode, your phone should be loaded with a custom recovery.

You mentioned that the phone reboots only into recovery mode, and that wiping cache didn't help. In this case I see no way out without wiping your data, however you can at least regain some of your data with ADB. Assuming drivers have been installed, connect your phone to the computer and use **ADB pull** to pull storage data and valuable app data to your computer. The exact procedure will take some skills to do, so please learn up if and only if you're determined to do so.

Things are easier if you can afford to give up some or all your data. Try **factory reset** first, which wipes app data but keeps storage data intact. Reboot after that to see if it boots properly. If not, the last resort is to use **Odin** to flash your phone in download mode. Again a complicated procedure, so I will not go into details unless it has really come to this.

Failing to boot even after Odin (or failing in the middle of the Odin process) means you have a fried motherboard. In that case, time to get a S7!

Comment: Somebody else noticed too? Thank god! It seems to be CWM (ClockWorkMod) from the lack of options. It could also be Philz (I think). But NOT TWRP.

Comment: @DanB Doesn't matter in this context though, OP wouldn't have done better even if the more intuitive TWRP was offered.

Comment: he may be able to flash/reflash his rom.